# Jquery - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for "-" in Object key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, kendo-grid

I am loading json data in kendo UI treelist by passing data in `transport`, i am getting error in this line :

```
e.success(data);
```

Error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
r.getter    @   kendo.all.min.js:1
n.extend.proxy.n.isFunction.f   @   jquery.min.js:2
n.extend.proxy.n.isFunction.f   @   jquery.min.js:2
```

[image]

```
  (function(d
   /**/) {
   return (d.endItems0_82002291-4_006)
  })
```

Problem is because of `endItems0_82002291-4_006`, `82002291-4` is the value of a json field and its also a field in kendo UI Treelist column. It works fine if I dont have `'-'` in the value like `82002291`.

Comment: so why not replacing '-' with '_' ?

Comment: try `return (d["endItems0_82002291-4_006"])`

Comment: This error is coming in jquery.min.js, so I am not able to modify it. I am also not sure where the key is set I am only putting it in value but some where jquery is using it as key.